# Is the 'IT.java' filename Suffix (instead of 'Test.java') for JUnit Integration Tests a convention?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, naming-conventions, convention

I was used to naming my JUnit Integration tests with a `*Test.java` on the end eg `DatabaseConnectionTest.java` and placing them in their own integration test directory: eg `test/integration/com...`

On joining a new project I was directed

> No, all the Tests go in the one directory, and we distinguish the Unit Tests from the Integration tests by pattern matching on the file name suffix.

So my file above would become `DatabaseConnectionIT.java`

Now I can see the logic in this. The test runner script can just pattern match for the files it is looking for, and all the tests are in the one location.

But I had never heard of the convention.

My question is:  **Is the `'IT.java'` filename Suffix (instead of `'Test.java'`) for JUnit Integration Tests a convention?**

Comment: In my opinion, it seems as much as a convention as INT for interface is.

Comment: It's a convention where you're at, which is enough. It's not a universal convention, for example, I group types of tests by directory, so the file and class names don't have funky abbreviations.

Comment: It's one of the [default patterns](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) recognized by the Maven Failsafe plugin, so it's hardly eyebrow-raising. ...what's your question, exactly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `IT.java` suffix is a convention used by the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/). All classes in the test directory that have the suffix `IT` are executed by this plugin in the `integragion-test` phase. (Tests with suffix `Test` are exectued by the [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) in the `test` phase.)

Comment: failsafe will also execute tests annotated with categories that are specified in the `groups` parameter https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit.html