# Open liberty and Test Class Name

Tags: jax-rs

Does test class/file names have to end as "IT" in order for the lilberty:dev maven goal to work? When I followed [Creating a RESTful web service](https://openliberty.io/guides/rest-intro.html) and issued  "mvn liberty:dev" command in the **finish** folder, once I changed the test file name EndpointIT.java to be EndpointTest and the class name EndpointIT EndpointTest(and nothing else), I saw test errors in the console when pressing ENTER.

If I changed file/class names to EndpointTestIT (with "IT" at the end), the test worked again.

It seems to me that a file and class must have "IT" suffix. Would this be a requirement a design feature? Or did I miss reading something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IT` suffix is a convention for Maven failsafe plugin, as discussed on [Is the 'IT.java' filename Suffix (instead of 'Test.java') for JUnit Integration Tests a convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077033/is-the-it-java-filename-suffix-instead-of-test-java-for-junit-integration/30080275):

> All classes in the test directory that have the suffix `IT` are executed by this plugin in the `integragion-test` phase. (Tests with suffix `Test` are exectued by the [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) in the `test` phase.)

Additional information can be found in the Baeldung tutorial, [Integration Testing with Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-integration-test).

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions!